# Android: how to create and hold mapview in memory for all activities to use

Tags: java, android, static, maps, startup

I want to reduce the startup time of google maps in my app. At the cost of some memory, I want to create the mapview on startup and then use it in whatever activities need it - without it ever being destroyed and recreated during app runtime. Is this possible? The problem as I see it is that the mapview wont actually initialize unless it is being used in a layout, and successive layouts are destroyed as the user moves between activities.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiZoomControls="false"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
map:uiTiltGestures="false" />
```

Comment: "successive layouts are destroyed as the user moves between activities" -- then get rid of the activities. Have one activity, with the map, that performs your desired functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for that BUT I would search something in life cycle of the activitiy. To achive the thing that you want to you would need to get the current state of the map/activity and save it in `onPause` and `onDestroy` methods. Then in `onCreate` and `onResume` you could check if you have any saved state if yes resume it using your own logick BUT in case of map and localization I don't think it is a good idea

Comment: thanks. I know that it's not a best practice, but currently users are seeing the map loading instead of an already loaded map and it's not a good experience. I've optimized load times as much as possible but it just isn't instantaneous. The only way for it to be instant is if the map is already loaded beforehand.

Comment: it won't solve your problem. The loading time depends on your location and internet connection. If you resume application 20-30 km off from last position than loading map from memory is just useless because you will still have to load it from start to center everything and load the part of the map that was not loaded before